# Missing URI template variable 'usuarioEntidade' for method parameter of type Long

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I try to pass a param in this method here

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distrito/{idEntidade}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(@PathVariable Long usuarioEntidade) throws ServletException { 

        Collection<Distritos> distritosBuscados = distritosService.buscarFiltro(usuarioEntidade);//parametro, que é o id_entidade, para passar na query de busca distritos
            return new ResponseEntity<>(distritosBuscados, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

and i got this error

```
Missing URI template variable 'usuarioEntidade' for method parameter of type Long
```

I'm calling this request on my front end right here

```
 idEntidade = Number(localStorage.getItem("idEntidade"));



$http({
        method : 'GET',
        url : '/user/distrito/' +idEntidade         
    }).then(function(response) {
        $scope.distritos = response.data;

    }, function(response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        console.log(response.status);
    });
};
```

then got an error..

```
Missing URI template variable 'usuarioEntidade' for method parameter of type Long
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that the name of the path variable in your rest request does not match the name of the variable passed to your java method.

You have two options:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distrito/{idEntidade}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(@PathVariable("idEntidade") Long usuarioEntidade)
```

Or:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distrito/{usuarioEntidade}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(@PathVariable Long usuarioEntidade)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make changed in buscarTodosDistritos() method as below

```
@PathVariable(value="idEntidade") Long usuarioEntidade  <--- add value in path variable
```

or

```
@PathVariable Long idEntidade   <--- or change variable name to map same as the one in the url
```

Answer (score 0):

Bolded parameters need to have same name

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distrito/{**idEntidade**}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity> buscarTodosDistritos(@PathVariable Long **usuarioEntidade**) throws ServletException

correct answer

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/distrito/{idEntidade}", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        public ResponseEntity<Collection<Distritos>> buscarTodosDistritos(@PathVariable Long idEntidade) throws ServletException
```